# Close.io API connection with Ruby syntax error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

My question pertains to connecting to the Close.io API and specifically updating the custom fields associated with leads - http://developer.close.io/#Leads

It states in your documentation that...

> custom: To update a single custom field without removing the others, 
>   use custom.field_name: updated_value instead ofcustom: { all:
>   'fields', listed: 'here' }.  You can also unset a single field by
>   using custom.field_name: null.

But this is causing some quirks in our project. Every update to a single field continues to remove the others.

So here's our code -

```
# We're using the close.io gem ( a ruby wrapper ) - https://github.com/taylorbrooks/closeio
# First we get the signed in user's email address 
# and query closeio to pull the appropriate lead associated with it

closeio_lead_id = (Closeio::Lead.where query: "email:['#{current_user.email}']")[0]['id']

#Next we're attempting to update the lead custom field of "kk_referral" with a float
(Closeio::Lead.update closeio_lead_id,
    custom: { kk_referral: Referral.where( :user_id => current_user.id).count.to_f }
    )

# And it works! Yay But then we run the next line to update another custom field... 
# the last action is erased. what the hell?

(Closeio::Lead.update closeio_lead_id,
    custom.kk_blog_posts_submitted: Comment.where( :user_id => current_user.id).count.to_f 
    )

# So we attempted to store the in a variable so we can replicate some of the direction provided in the documentation.
closeio_comment = Comment.where( :user_id => current_user.id).count.to_f
(Closeio::Lead.update closeio_lead_id,
    custom.kk_blog_posts_submitted: closeio_comment 
    )

# And nothing is coming through. AHhhh. Only the original syntax works.
```

When attempting to use the syntax provided in the documentation....

```
custom.field_name: some_variable_storing_a_float
```

I get a syntax error relating to the colon after field_name.

And when attempting to use more friendly Ruby syntax....

```
custom.field_name => some_variable_storing_a_float
```

I get an error on using the custom local variable. (Exactly reads "NameError: undefined local variable or method `custom' for main:Object )

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out folks.
Here's the syntax -

```
Closeio::Lead.update 'lead_id', 'custom.Field Name' => 'Value'
```